# convert char* to char? c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I figured this question had been asked a million times but I can't find the answer anywhere. Should be simple. Ok so I have a struct in my .h file:

```
struct question{
    string programNum;
    string programDesc;
    string programPoints;
    string programInput;
    char programQuestion;
};
```

And then I have function initiated in the .h and arguments in .cpp:

```
void setQuestionFileName(question q, char fileName){
    q.programQuestion = fileName;

}
```

Ok all is well so far. Now in main I have the issue of trying to store argv[1] in programQuestion:

```
char* fileName = argv[count+1];
```

followed by:

```
setQuestionFileName(questions[count],fileName);
cout << questions[count].programQuestion << endl;
```

I'm not real good with pointers so if anyone could help me store the char* argv into the char questions[count].programQuestion that would be amazing. Thank you!

Comment: It is not possible. A `char` is one character. A string is many characters. Go back to the book you're learning from and see some of its examples of string handling.

Comment: then why does `cout << filename << endl;` print "q1.txt" to the screen? That looks like 6 characters to me

Comment: The most obvious way to go from `char*` to `char` is to simply dereference the `char*` (i.e. put an asterisk in front of it).  But somehow, I doubt this is actually desired.

Comment: I don't know what `filename` is, it doesn't appear in any of the code in the question. It's not a `char`. It might be a `char*`, in which case apparently it points to a string containing the characters `q1.txt`.

Comment: Everything that was already said applies. Plus, you have another problem: Since you are passing the `question` parameter by value into `setQuestionName`, your are assigning `fileName` to the local copy and the value gets never populated outside that function. Change the function signature to `void setQuestionFileName(question* q, char fileName)`.

Comment: I'd say, if you don't understand pointers by now, throw your current book away and try another one.

Comment: I think it would help if you gave us the complete / more complete code, not all of those snippets.

Comment: Also since the question is tagged as C++, you should be using std::string instead of char*

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to post the code, I think it may work better that way. This is the .h:

```
      using namespace std;
      // Data

      struct question{
      string programNum;
      string programDesc;
      string programPoints;
      string programInput;
      char* programQuestion;
      };

      void setQuestionFileName(question* q, char* fileName);
      void display(question* q);
      void display(question* q);
```

This is the .cpp

```
    using namespace std;


    void setQuestionFileName(question* q, char* fileName){
        strcpy(q->programQuestion, fileName);
    }

    void display(question* q){

           cout << "Description           =  "   << q->programDesc     << endl;
           cout << "Number of Points      =  "   << q->programPoints   << endl;
           cout << "Name of Question File =  "   << q->programQuestion << endl;

    }

    // Not used or tested yet
    int myCompare (const void * a, const void * b ) {
               const char *pa = *(const char**)a;
               const char *pb = *(const char**)b;

               return strcmp(pa,pb);
     }
```

And main.cpp:

```
     using namespace std;

     int main(int argc, char* argv[]){                                                              //or char** argv
     question* questions[argc-1];                                                           //Array of questions to be filled by loop.
     int sizeOfQuestions = argc;                                                                    //number of questions passed in at run time
     int numLines = 0;                                                                          //number of lines in file
     for(int i=0;i<argc;i++){                                                                   //Test loop to make sure the command line file names are read in
              std::cout << argv[i] << " says hello" << std::endl;
     }
     for(int count=0;count<sizeOfQuestions-1;count++){                                          //This loop places the information from the files into structs
     //char fileName = argv[count+1];
     char* fileName = argv[count+1];
     cout << "Problem number:  " << count+1 << "\t Working with file " << fileName << endl;
     std::fstream questionFile (fileName, std::fstream::in);                                    //Open the file
     if(questionFile.good()){
        cout << "File Opened" << endl;
        setQuestionFileName(questions[count],fileName);
        cout << questions[count]->programQuestion << endl;
        getline(questionFile,questions[count]->programNum);
        getline(questionFile,questions[count]->programDesc);
        getline(questionFile,questions[count]->programPoints);
        getline(questionFile,questions[count]->programInput);
        display(questions[count]);
        questionFile.close();
     }else{
        cout << "Could not open file!!!" << endl;
     }

 }

 return 0;

}
```

The way it is now, I'm getting a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `programQuestion` from `char` to `char*`

And, this function

```
void setQuestionFileName(question q, char fileName){
    q.programQuestion = fileName;

}
```

I think it should be

```
void setQuestionFileName(question& q, char* fileName){
    strcpy(q.programQuestion, fileName);
}
```

Hardly there is a file with only 1-character name.

Comment: I tried that but for some reason the program breaks when it gets to the part where setQuestionFileName is called. The file name is never printed.

Comment: Change the signature to `setQuestionFileName(question* q, char fileName)`. See my comment on the question.

Comment: And the `struct question` has to be adjusted to either use `char const* fileName;` when simply assigning the pointer or `char fileName[SOME_VALUE];`.

Comment: @user2990286: could you provide more code & error that you got.

Comment: I changed everything, but now I get a segmentation fault when it tries to run setQuestionFileName.

Comment: @user2990286: if you want to use pointer, first you have to allocate enough space for it. I suggest you read some ebook on C/C++ first.